# Using MVC 4 CSS template instead of MVC 5 bootstrap.css files

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

So I am trying to change the CSS up in MVC 5 from the default bootstrap view that it renders.  In some examples I have seen from MVC 4 which didn't use bootstrap by default I don't believe, it has a much better looking template in my opinion. MVC 5 has the plain black bar across the top, I know MVC 4 is also simple but I prefer that one.  The only problem is I can't seem to find the source code, or the original CSS files they used for it anywhere?  Every tutorial that I can find simply uses images instead of providing the files that I would need to add it to my project.

Here is the look I am going for...

http://i1.asp.net/media/45041/mvc4-restyled-templates.png?raw=true&cdn_id=2014-05-05-001

The default look that MVC 5 using bootstrap provides is..

http://eduardopires.net.br/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/aspnet_mvc5_build.jpg

Any suggestions on how I might switch to the previous version, or where I might find the proper CSS files to change it?  I am trying to do this to an existing project so starting over really isn't an option.  Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: I think the MVC4 template isn't responsive though, you should consider that first.

Answer (score 0):

You can install MVC4 side by side with MVC5 and create web project with MVC4 template. From there you can obtain the css you're looking